# Cookies not working on different pages

Tags: php, cookies

Ok I have a cookie set, and I can clearly see it if I go to private data in Firefox... ok so when I echo it on one page in a certain directory it works, (www.example.com/dir), but on the index page of the site (www.example.com), it wont echo, it says the cookie is not set. Yes I have cookies enabled, yes I tried clearing cache and all that. Any ideas? PHP btw

Comment: You might find [`$cookie->setPath($path)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L104) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Which directory are you in when the cookie gets set?

From the [PHP manual on setcookie()](http://de3.php.net/setcookie), emphasis mine:

> **Path**
>
> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain . If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain . **The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.**

Answer (score 25):

Cookies can be bound to a specific domain, subdomain, path, and protocol (http/https). You need to specify the path when setting the cookie in PHP:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Value", time()+3600 , '/' );
```

The fourth parameter binds it to the root of the site and it will be available in any subdirectory of the main site.

If you want it available on the main domain and any subdomain, supply the fifth parameter like this:

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Value", time()+3600 , '/', '.example.com' );
```

Now it will be readable at:

> www.example.com
>   example.com/newdir
>   awesome.example.com/newdir

Comment: Adding the '/', '.example.com' at the end solved this issue for me

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the path that the cookie is being set.

If it's not `'/'`, there's your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Yes try this, I was also facing this problem but resolved by below code.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", "Value", time()+3600 , '/' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your path option; the default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in. Because you're setting the cookie in the directory /dir , its only available within that directory or below it.

You get around this by explicitly setting the path, ie.

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)
```

Set the path to "/".

Answer (score 1):

```
setcookie("Cookie_name", "Cookie_Value", time()+3600 , '/' );
```

fourth parameter (`'/'`) will make your cookies accessible to pages in parent directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the $path to / in `setcookie()`, if you want to access it in all directories

Answer (score 0):

Cookies Must Be Set Before Page Output !!!
Since cookies are sent by the script to the browser in the HTTP headers, before your page is sent, they must be set **before you even send a single line of HTML or any other page output**. The moment you send any sort of output, you are signalling the end of the HTTP headers. When that happens, you can no longer set any cookie. If you try, the setcookie() function will return FALSE, and the cookie will not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie('cookie_username', $cookie_username, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day,  '/' denotes cookie available in entire directory.
```

and in another page:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['cookie_username'];
```

also make sure that browser is not blocking cookies.

If you want to use cookies in sub domain also:

```
setcookie('cookie_username', $cookie_username, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", ".subdomain.com"); // 86400 = 1 day,  '/' denotes cookie available in entire directory.
```