# mysqli_fetch_array no result

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

This is a part of my header file:

```
    $username = $_COOKIE["empirebattles"];
    $userdata_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    $userdata = mysqli_fetch_array($userdata_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

I got the value of the cookie, ran a query with it and then fetched the array, why does it not seem to print the correct value when I write:

```
echo $userdata["username"];
```

It's probably a small error, but all help is appreciated.

Comment: This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: Not really, as it isn't a public site.

Comment: try this:  $userdata = $userdata_query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: do var_dump($userdata) - is anything in it at all?

Comment: Echoed NULL. Is that bad?

Comment: Then your query did not find any results.

Comment: var_dump($username): what you have got?

Comment: It seems my cookie isn't working.

Comment: @user2999920 : then problem is in your cookie. fix it then everything should work :)

Comment: My cookie is working in the root and account directory (all the other ones) but not this one.

Comment: @user2999920 : Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038760/cookies-not-working-on-different-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
   $username = isset($_COOKIE["empirebattles"]) ? $_COOKIE["empirebattles"] : false ;
    if($username){
        $userdata_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
        $userdata = mysqli_fetch_array($userdata_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo $userdata["username"];
    }
    else{

     echo "no username selected!";
    }
```

Comment: I have checked if any username available in cookie. if no username then just set it to false else run your query.

Comment: It only works in my home.php file, not my header file though. Any idea why?

Comment: @user2999920: Yes. Your cookie available in home.php not available in this file. set your cookiecorrectly it will solve your problem. checkout this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038760/cookies-not-working-on-different-pages

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's fine. setcookie("empirebattles",$username,time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),"/", ".empirebattles.co.uk");

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44518/discussion-between-user2999920-and-awlad-liton)

Comment: @user2999920 if this solution works, accept the answer to help others to choose best solution

Answer (score 1):

this may sound stupid, but have you included your connetion to the database, without a DB connection then you wont get a return. before the query, make sure you have the following

```
<?php include('Connection_To_Database.php') ?>
```

you maye have overlooked this

Comment: sorry, i wasnt calling you stupid, but i know what it is like to sit there scripting, you can easily forget the simple things! It was just a suggestion.